# Convert non-tabular input data to CSV text file

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, text-parsing, string-parsing

I'm new to Python and need some advice.

My final goal is to produce a CSV text file that I can to import to an EXCEL spreadsheet.

The input data text file is produced from a legacy application in the following format:

Last Name: Smith
First Name: Ron
Department: Accounting
Position: Data Entry Clerk
Work Phone Ext.: 7131
Mobile: 416-999-9999
Email ID: rs@info.com
-----------------------------------
Last Name: Jones
First Name: Rick
Department: Accounting
Position: Data Entry Clerk
Work Phone Ext.:
Mobile: 416-999-9999
Email ID:
-----------------------------------
Last Name: Snow
First Name: Greg "Red"
Department:
Position: Contractor, DB Admin
Work Phone Ext.:
Mobile: 416-999-9999
Email ID:
-----------------------------------

**Note that generic labels (last name, first name...) are always  generated and some lables may not contain any data.**

My final output should look like...

Last Name,First Name,Department,Position,Work Phone Ext.,Mobile,Email ID
Smith,Ron,Accounting,Data Entry Clerk,7131,416-999-9999,rs@info.com
Jones,Rick,Accounting,Data Entry Clerk,,416-999-9999,
Snow,"Greg ""Red""",,"Contractor, DB Admin",,416-999-9999,

Comment: What's your question? What kind of advice do you need?

Comment: What function can I use to convert my input which is in tabular format  to row format?

Comment: I don't think there's a function (in the standard library, anyhow) that will do the whole job for you. But if you write a simple parser to convert each "tabular" entry into a list or dict, you can then use the 'csv' module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write them out as well-formed CSV.